# Best way to change vue slots pattern into React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

In my vue application, i am using slots for some block of contents. Now, i have to migrate my application into react. While exploring react, i got to know **props.children** will work similar as slot works.

But, i am not sure what will be the proper way to use this pattern in react.

**Here is the sample of code in vue**

```
 <template>
    <div class="badge-box">
        <span :class="badgeClass" :style="badgeStyle">
            <span v-if="shape !=='dot'" class="line-break">
                <slot>
                    {{text}}
                </slot>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span v-if="shape ==='dot'" class="line-break" style="margin-left: 8px;">
            <slot name="dotShape">
                {{text}}
            </slot>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   name:'sample'
   props: {
     text: { type: string }
   
   }
 
 }
</script>
```

How to change this vue slot pattern into React using props.children?

Comment: There are several patterns in React that correlate closely with Vue slots, namely "function as prop" and "function as child". props.children alone works only as default slot without slotProps

Comment: Can you suggest me for above vue code ? example also will work for me for better understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several patterns in React that correlate closely with Vue slots.

`props.children` can be used, but only for `default` slot  with no `slotProps`. For named slot additional props can be used. Default slot content `<slot>{{text}}</slot>` can be conditionally rendered when no children are provided:

```
let MyComp = props => (
  ...
  <div class="default-slot">{{props.children ?? props.text}}</div>
  ...
  <div class="named-slot">{{props.named ?? props.text}}</div>
  ...
)
```

and

```
<MyComp named={<p>Named content</p>}>
  <p>Default content</p>
</MyComp>
```

*Function as child* and *function as prop* patterns serve the same purpose but allow to replace slots with `slotProps`. A child can pass parameters to parent scope through a callback:

```
let MyComp = props => (
  ...
  <div class="default-slot">{{props.children?.('foo') ?? props.text}}</div>
  ...
  <div class="named-slot">{{props.named?.('bar') ?? props.text}}</div>
  ...
)
```

and

```
<MyComp named={param => <p>Named content {{param}}</p>}>{
  param => <p>Default content {{param}}</p>
}</MyComp>
```

Comment: How would you type this prop in typescript?

Comment: Something like `{ children?: (s: string) => ReactNode, named?: ..same... }`

Answer (score 2):

Vue slots can be copied pretty easily.

Here is an example of a *named* slot that exposes an object to the parent component.

```
function Parent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child slot={(slotItemData: any) => <div>Message: {slotItemData.message}</div>}></Child>
    </div>
  );
}

function Child(props: any) {
  let slotItemData = {
    message: "Hello form child",
  };

  return <div>{props.slot?.(slotItemData)}</div>;
}
```

**Message: Hello form child**

Answer (score 1):

In React, you can pass text or any other content between the opening and closing tags of a component using the children prop. Here is an example of how you could pass the text between the button tags from the parent MyButtonGroup component to the MyButton child component:

This is MyButtonGroup.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import MyButton from './MyButton';

function MyButtonGroup() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyButton>Hello</MyButton>
      <MyButton>World</MyButton>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyButtonGroup;
```

This is MyButton.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

function MyButton({ children }) {
  return (
    <button>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}

export default MyButton;
```

In the example above, the MyButton component receives the text between its opening and closing tags as the children prop. It then renders that text inside the button element using curly braces {} to access the children prop value. The MyButtonGroup parent component passes the text as a child of each MyButton component.

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you are using JSX/TSX in functional React

```
const Component ({text}) => {
    return (
        <div class="badge-box">
            <span :class="badgeClass" :style="badgeStyle">
                <span v-if="shape !=='dot'" class="line-break">
                    {{text}}
                </span>
            </span>
            <span v-if="shape ==='dot'" class="line-break" style="margin-left: 8px;">
                {{text}}
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

will do what you want. If you are using class component, put it in the render method.